# Use intersection in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-3, intersection

I want to use the tool intersects in the field calculator. If the condition is true, I want to set a result field to a specific number. The field calculator doesn't accept my expression but I can not find the reason for the error. Can you please help me.

```
CASE
WHEN intersects('layer1', 'layer2') = true THEN 1
WHEN intersects('layer1', 'layer3') = true THEN 2
END
```

the error says:

> syntax error, unexpected NUMBER_INT, expecting WHEN or ELSE or END
>   syntax error, unexpected END, expecting $end

I work with QGIS 3.4 (Madeira)

Answer (score 9):

The `intersects` function requires two geometries (not layers) as input requirements as described in the help section of the field calculator:

> **intersects(geometry a, geometry b)**
>
> Tests whether a geometry intersects another. Returns true if the geometries spatially intersect (share any portion of space) and false if they do not.

If you want to use layer names, install the **refFunctions** plugin which adds more functions to the field calculator such as:

> **geomintersects(targetLayer,targetField)**
>
> Retrieve target field value when source feature intersects target feature in target layer.

---

Assuming you are using the field calculator on `layer1`, you could use something like the following:

```
CASE
WHEN geomintersects('layer2', 'any_layer2_FieldName') THEN 1
WHEN geomintersects('layer3', 'any_layer3_FieldName') THEN 2
END
```

Comment: I want to change always the same field (from the same layer). My layer1 contains different polygons, wich represent the location of buildings. With the intersect operation I want to change always the field "Geb_Nutz" (layer1), wich shows the kind of use for the building. For all the buildings, that intersect layer1 and layer2, I want to set "Geb_Nutz" to 1. For all the buildings, that intersect layer1 and layer3, I want to set "Geb_Nutz" to 2. I tried the following operation, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: CASE
WHEN geomintersects('layer2',"Geb_Nutz") THEN 1
WHEN geomintersects('layer3',"Geb_Nutz") THEN 2
END

Comment: If you want to change the field "Geb_Nutz" then you need to provide any field name from layer2 and layer3 for the expression. **Do not** use "Geb_Nutz" because that is the field you want to change. So select layer1, go to the field calculator, select to update your chosen field and use the expression: `CASE
WHEN geomintersects('layer2', 'layer2_field') THEN 1
WHEN geomintersects('layer3', 'layer3_field') THEN 2
END`

Comment: Thanks for quoting refFunctions, I appreciated, helped me a lot using geomintersects function.